# Swift: How to use NSUserDefaults to store separate information for each cell in Table View

Tags: ios, swift

and thanks in advance for helping me out if you can. I'm still very new to Swift but looking forward to learning quickly so I can help others here on the forum.

For now, I have a problem that I need to solve and I have no idea where to start. Hypothetically, my goal is to achieve something like the following:

**First View: User enters names of cities they have visited**

**Second View: User enters names of museums they saw in that city**

**Then, each time the user selects a city on the first View, the stored 'museum' information will be displayed.**

So far, I've managed to get NSUserDefaults functional, but the same data is shown regardless of the cell that I select from the list on the initial View.

I am using the specific name of the array throughout the app to store, display and read data from NSUserDefaults, and I want to know the best way to edit this so that the app will check which cell I select and then display the appropriate information (or none if there hasn't been any entered for that cell).

I hope that was a good explanation, I know it was long - sorry. Below is my code so far. Any input or suggestions are welcome. Thank you!

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var detailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var detailTableView: UITableView!

    var receivedString:String = ""        
    var cell0Array:[NSString] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        detailTextField.delegate = self
        detailTableView.delegate = self
        detailTableView.dataSource = self

        titleLabel.text = receivedString

        if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("cell0Array") != nil {
        cell0Array = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("cell0Array") as! [NSString]
        } else {
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        let now = NSDate()

        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()

        formatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
        formatter.timeStyle = .NoStyle

        let date = formatter.stringFromDate(now)

        let detailTextFieldContents = detailTextField.text
        let token = "\(date): \(detailTextFieldContents!)lb"
        cell0Array.insert(token, atIndex: 0)

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(cell0Array, forKey: "cell0Array")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

        detailTextField.text = ""
        detailTextField.resignFirstResponder()

        self.detailTableView.reloadData()

        return true
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cell0Array.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let detailCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("detailCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        let detailItem = cell0Array[indexPath.row]

        detailCell.textLabel!.text = detailItem as String
        detailCell.textLabel!.textAlignment = .Center

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        return detailCell
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One obvious problem is this line:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // ...
    cell0Array.insert(token, atIndex: 0)
    // ...
}
```

Instead of figuring out which row of the table this text field's cell is in, and placing the value at that index, you are always inserting `token` at index 0. Thus there is no correspondence between rows and entries in `cell0Array`.

Comment: Thanks! I do understand that my code is flawed, and I recognize that this is the problem. Can you point me in the right direction? Thanks again.

Comment: Sure, this is a downloadable project where the user can enter text in a text field in a table cell and the model is updated according to what row was edited. https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch08p447editInsertAndRearrangeRows/ch21p741editInsertAndRearrangeRows/RootViewController.swift

Comment: Thanks Matt, I really appreciate it. I'll have a read and see what I can learn.

Comment: In particular notice how `textFieldDidEndEditing` behaves. It figures out first _what row this is_. (In my case I also have two sections so we also need to know what section this is.) That way, it can proceed to update the model correctly.